# Create Collections on Kindle DX via API?

Tags: java, kindle

Just looking for a while for a way to create collections on my Kindle DX by API...but didn't find one but only tools that should do it but didnt work.

Does anyone know an API that would enable me to create collections with Java or at least c#?

I still asked amazon but they only provided info how to create on the kindle although I mentioned I'm looking for an API...

Answer (score 1):

Check out Calibre (open source e-book manager program). They have a collection manager plugin and read the source.

Here is a nice forum post where the Kindle Collection management (with Calibre) is described: http://www.mobileread.com/forums/showthread.php?t=118635

HTH

Comment: I just tried calibre...imported ebooks from file structure..after transferring I saw that there was no collection created on my kindle...anybody know how to do that?